# r.js: How to uglify and concatenate all amd modules into a single file?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js, js-amd

My project workspace looks something like this.

```
Modules
|--> Src
|   |--> Application
|   |       |--> Application.js
|   |--> Home
|   |       |--> Home.js
|   |--> Utils
|   |       |--> Utils.js
|--> Vendors
|   |--> Underscore
|   |       |--> Underscore.js
|   |--> jQuery
|   |       |--> jQuery.js
|   |--> Require
|   |       |--> require.js
            |--> r.js
```

I am using r.js library to uglify and bundle all above files, but it is not working for me.

**// build.js**

```
({
    baseUrl: 'Modules/'
,   include: ["../main"]
,   optimize: 'uglify'
,   out: 'build/bundle.js'
,   wrap: true
})
```

**// main.js**

```
require.config({
    "paths": {
        "Application": "Src/Application/Application",
        "Home": "Src/Home/Home",
        "Utils": "Src/Utils/Utils",
        "Underscore": "Vendor/Underscore/Underscore",
    }
})
```

```
//Command to optimize files using r.js.
node path/to/r.js -o build.js
```

After executing the above command the minified file looks like below.

```
//javascript.min.js (Actual Result)
(function () {
reuiqre.config({
    paths: {
        "Application": "Src/Application/Application",
        "Home": "Src/Home/Home",
        "Utils": "Src/Utils/Utils"
    }
});
define("../main", function(){});

}());
```

Where as I expect something like this.

```
//javascript.min.js (Expected result)
(function(){
    /* START   =>  underscore.js, jquery and other libraries code
            3RD PARTY LIBRARIES
    END     =>underscore.js, jquery and other libraries code
    */
    define('Home', ['Deps'], function(dep){ /** Content */ });
    define('Utils', ['Deps'], function(dep){ /** Content */ });
    define('Application', ['Deps'], function(dep){ /** Content */ });
}());
```

Can someone please tell me whether this can be achieved by using r.js or not ?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you miss the onBuildRead method but I'm not sure. Please check this article https://volaresystems.com/technical-posts/optimizing-javascript-and-css-files-using-requirejs-and-rjs-in-an-aspnet-mvc-app

Comment: @Rajibkarmaker I have tried that method, it just copy all the files and put it in the output directory, nothing else. When I call main.js, the no. of requests are same. Bdw thanks for the response.